# How can I change the index correct in a list? (Python)

Tags: python

I wrote some code to calculate the maximum path in a triangle.

```
     75
   95 64
  17 47 82
 18 35 87 10
20 04 82 47 65
```

The maximum path sum is `75+95+82+87+82`. I want that it calculates the maximum path from the adjecent numbers under the current layer. For example the maximum path sum must be: `75+95+47+87+82`, because `47` 'touches' 95 and `82`doesn't. In the layer under this there is a choice between `35` and `87`. So there is always a choice between two numbers. Does anyone how I can do this? This is my code:

```
lst = [[72], 
    [95,64], 
    [17,47,82], 
    [18,35,87,10],
    [20,4,82,47,65]]
something = 1
i = 0
mid = 0
while something != 0:
    for x in lst:
        new = max(lst[i])
        print(new)
        i += 1
        mid += new
    something = 0
print(mid)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-path-sum-triangle/) answer your question ?

Comment: Yeah method 5 does. Do you know what the letter `m` means in method 5, python 3?

Comment: It seems to be the depth of your triangle, i.e. `m = len(tri)-1`. Moreover, `N` and `n` are not used in this code so you can remove it.

Comment: @NewbieProgram I updated my answer! Now it should work

Comment: I appreciate it!

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen, can you explain what `lambda` and `enumerate` do?

Comment: @NewbieProgram I updated my answer with more details! I think it will be clear now, else just ask me again :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each row the choice should be between two values. If you always want to pick the maximum between those two values, the first solution works. If you want to maximize the sum by sometimes picking the lower value, the second solution works.

```
values = []

index = 0 # the index of the 'max' number in the first row

for row in lst:
    section = row[index:index+2] 
    value = max(section) 
    index = row.index(value) 
    values.append(value)
```

In this code we loop through each row, where the first row is just `[75]`, the second row is `[95, 64]`, etc.

For each row, we take the two numbers that are directly below our previous choice. For the first row, the choice must always be number in position `0`, as it's the only number.

Then, we take the max of those two numbers. Then we take the index of that max number, which we will use to select the new two numbers on the next iteration.

Now all the values are stored in `value`. We can use `sum(values)` to get the sum.

**Second solution**

```
import itertools

# Create a new pyramid where each cell is the index of each number
index_lst = [[x for x in range(len(l))] for l in lst]

# Now index_lst looks like this:
# [[0], 
# [0, 1], 
# [0, 1, 2], 
# [0, 1, 2, 3], 
# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]

# get all possible paths, including those that are not valid such as [0, 0, 0, 0, 4]
all_possible_paths = itertools.product(*index_lst) 


def check_validity(path):
    # check the step size for each path.
    # A step it should always be less then 2
    # If the differene is too large, then it's not a valid path
    for x in range(0,len(path)-1):
        difference = abs(path[x] - path[x+1])
        if difference > 1:
            return False
    return True

# Filter out all the paths that are not valid
valid_path = []
for path in all_possible_paths:
    if check_validity(path):
        valid_path.append(path)
        

# For all the valid paths, get the path that returns the maximum value
# here the max funciton takes in the paths, and then converts the path to the sum of the values

optimal_path = max(valid_path, key = lambda e: sum([lst[row][index] for row, index in enumerate(e)]))

# Actually conver the optimal path to values
optimal_values = [lst[row][index] for row, index in enumerate(optimal_path)]


print(optimal_path)
print(optimal_values)
print(sum(optimal_values))
```

*edit*: Some extra details about this line

```
optimal_path = max(valid_path, key = lambda e: sum([lst[row][index] for row, index in enumerate(e)]))
```

First, the max function can take a key parameter. This just tells the max function how it should actually determine the max. For example, with input `[[0,5],[1,0]]` I can use the key parameter to tell max to use the second elements (i..e, 5 and 0) in each list to determine the max, instead of 0 and 1.

In this case, we give it a lambda function. This basically means we pass a function as the key parameter, without defining the function before hand. It is conceptually imilar to doing this

```
def fun(e):
   # do some stuff

optimal_path = max(valid_path, key = fun(e))
```

Next, I use a list comprehension. That's just a shorter way of writing a for loop.

```
[lst[row][index] for row, index in enumerate(e)]
```

Is the same thing as doing

```
 output = [] 
 for row, index in enumerate(e):
     output.append(lst[row][index])
```

The `enumerate` takes an iterable (like `['a','b','c']`) and also gives the index for each element. Thus  `list(enumerate(a))` returns `[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]`. In the for loop I immediately assign them to `row` and `index`.

Comment: this gets the maximum number of each successive row, not the continuous path with maximum sum!

Comment: @mozway Perhaps I misunderstand but I think you're wrong. The maximum number of each successive row would be `[72, 95, 82, 87, 82]`. The method in my answer returns `[72, 95, 47, 87, 82]`

Comment: Try your code on `[[1], [1, 0], [1, 0, 99]]`, the max sum is 100 (1->0->99), your solution shows 3 ;)

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I interpreted the question as "the path by taking the maximum of the two values below the max value" instead of "the maximum path by taking the maximum of the two values below the current value"

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen Okay, maybe I wasn't clear. I meant what mozway said.

Answer (score 0):

The "triangle" is an example of a *graph* (in the computer science sense, not the maths sense).

You will have to use recursion in order to solve this, or some kind of stochastic algorithm. Personally, I'd use the genetic algorithm since the problem is combinatorial.